# Function invisible from macrolet?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, asdf

I have an ASDF system with the following code in it:

```
;; testproj.asd
(asdf:defsystem #:testproj
  :serial t
  :components ((:file "testproj")))
```

```
;; testproj.lisp
(defpackage #:testproj
  (:use #:cl))

(in-package #:testproj)

(defun baz (x) x)

(defun bar ()
  (macrolet ((mac ()
           (baz 100)))
    (mac)))
```

When I try to load it, SBCL sometimes complains that the function BAZ is undefined when trying to expand the macro, but sometimes it doesn't. I can't seem to reproduce this behavior when loading testproj.lisp directly, but I guess it doesn't prove much, since I can't reliably reproduce it otherwise, either. Am I doing something wrong and incurring undefined behavior? Is this a bug with ASDF/SBCL? What is going on? :S